# How to recognize tense in the sentence?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense

could you please explain in which tense is the sentence?

> I’ve been sick and haven’t been able to do the library research I need for the paper.

Is it present perfect or not?

Comment: Yes, "I've been sick" and "haven't been able ..." are present perfect tense clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is present perfect, starting in the past and continuing to the present.

> have been sick
>   haven't been able to do

You could also change "need" to "have needed to"

> I’ve been sick and haven’t been able to do the library research I **have needed to** for the paper.

Comment: I don't like the change to "I have needed". Simple present is better for a state continuing into the future.